# pointer-like constant memory type in Rust

Tags: rust

I am writing a simple network protocol implementation in Rust as an exercise. It will be reading a Protocol Data Unit from a socket to memory and proceed to parse its components into Rust `struct` with appropriate fields.

What would be the best type for memory block which could be used in parsing? I should be able to call separate functions to parse parts of it at different offsets. In C I would go with simple `const char *`. Looks like raw pointers in Rust are possible but do not provide any additional safety benefits since most operations on them are unsafe and there are no bounds checking.

On the other hand, I would like to keep the PDU block on the heap as a continuous memory block, exactly as it was read from the socket. In other words, I do not ant any representation overhead.

Comment: Surely you'd use `Vec<u8>` ?

Comment: my data structure is readonly. Can I make it readonly? Also how efficient is index access? For example, doing repeatedly `vec[n]` version calculating `vec+n` in C once and using it repeatedly.

Comment: Which of your requirements are not met by `&[u8]`?

Comment: @the8472 bounds checking (reading past allocated memory block), read-only (I guess I can add `const`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a heap allocated immutable buffer of bytes [`Vec<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) is the obvious choice.

From the tone of your question, I suspect you might be thinking there is too much overhead with a Vec - not so:

- It contains only a pointer to the allocated heap memory and the size. That is the minimum you could get away with, really, if you want a safe place to store your protocol message
- In line with the philosophy of rust: you only pay for the features you use.
- Because it is a fundamental building block, the std library designers have made a lot of guarantees about it's design that allow it to be used in a very low overhead way. I recommend reading the std library docs linked above - there is a section on these guarantees.

> Can I make it read-only?

Yes, all variables in rust are immutable unless you declare them `mut`. You can even start with it being mutable (necessary if you intend to fill the buffer to begin with) and then rebind to an immutable variable.

> Also how efficient is index access? For example, doing repeatedly vec[n] version calculating vec+n in C once and using it repeatedly.

Before worrying about that, I recommend writing your code in the way that is clearest and most logical. The compiler will make optimizations that may well make these concerns meaningless. If, after profiling, you have performance issues then sure there are tweaks you could make.

If you want to access a single element multiple times, you could take a reference to it:

```
let el = &buf[n];
```

then use `*el` to reference the element.

If you want to move through the buffer sequentially, then use an iterator, rather than sequentially indexing the bytes. An iterator is implemented with pointers internally.

If you want to pass around a part of the buffer, without copying, then take a slice:

```
let s1 = &buf[10..12];
// s1 now contains a slice of bytes 10 through 12
```

Again, a slice is low overhead: a pointer to the start and a length.

All of the above is safe code. There are also unsafe functions (eg. `get_unchecked` to access an element without bounds checking). You can even get a raw pointer with `as_ptr()` if you really need it.

Comment: *That is the minimum you could get away with, really* - not quite, `Box<[u8]>` would be smaller.